# Break in data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers, yaxis

I know that Hadley has made a point about not inserting breaks in data,
but, is there a way of putting a break in this data in ggplot 2? I really like the package and am dreading having to change all my graphs and learn another package.

My data looks like this - I have supplied examples until I publish, I have a lot of data at a lower end and a few outliers at the higher end,

```
Date        Site    Al
07/10/2014  Bo6     32
07/10/2014  Bo1     32
07/10/2014  Bo3     40
07/10/2014  Bo4     60
07/10/2014  Bo5     51
07/10/2014  B14
07/10/2014  B4
07/10/2014  B3
07/10/2014  B5
07/10/2014  B8
07/10/2014  B11
07/10/2014  B13
14/10/2014  Bo6
14/10/2014  Bo1   100
14/10/2014  Bo3   300
14/10/2014  Bo5   2000
14/10/2014  Bo4   3000
14/10/2014  B14
14/10/2014  B3
14/10/2014  B4
14/10/2014  B5
14/10/2014  B8
14/10/2014  B12
4/10/2014   B11
14/10/2014  B13
28/10/2014  Bo4  1000
28/10/2014  Bo5  2000
28/10/2014  Bo6  3000
28/10/2014  B3
28/10/2014  B4
28/10/2014  B5
28/10/2014  B6
28/10/2014  B7
28/10/2014  B8
28/10/2014  B9
28/10/2014  B10
28/10/2014  B11
28/10/2014  B12
28/10/2014  B13
28/10/2014  B14
31/10/2014  B1
31/10/2014  D1
```

I have used the following code:-

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(magrittr)
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
require(cowplot)
require(grid)
require(scales)
setwd("~/Documents/Results")
mydata <- read.csv("Metals sheet R.csv")
L <- subset(mydata, Site =="Bo1"| Site == "Bo2"| Site == "Bo3"| Site       == "Bo4"| Site == "Bo5" | Site == "Bo6", select = c(Site,Date,Al))
L$Date <- as.Date(L$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
I <- ggplot(data=L, aes(x=Date, y=Al, colour=Site)) +
geom_point() + 
labs(title = "Total aluminium in the Bowydd
   2014-2015.", x = "Month 2014/2015",
   y = "Total concentration (mg/L)") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%m") +      theme_get()
 r2 <- I + geom_hline(aes(yintercept= 10, linetype = "NRW limit"),     colour= 'red') +
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept= 75.5, linetype = "Geochemical atlas limit"), colour= 'blue') +
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "Limit", values = c(2, 2), 
                    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("blue", "red"))))
ggdraw(r2) + draw_figure_label(label = "(a)", position ="top.left")
```

As you can see the high points obscure the data below. Is it possible to put a break in the data on the y axis or better to log transform? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the _real_ graphics package for the one image and make it look like your other images

Comment: Thanks! sounds plausible!

Comment: `scale_y_log10` makes it look much better. Hadley thinks (not unreasonably) that broken y-axes are misleading, so they're not easy to build in ggplot2.